# Kind of Gronwall Inequality

Tags: analysis, integral-inequality, functional-inequalities, gronwall-type-inequality

Does somebody knows if it is possible to obtain an inequality (like for Gronwall inequality) on $f$ if $f$ verify
$$ f(t) \leq A+\int_0^{2t} g(s)f(s) ds $$.
Where $f$ and $g$ are as smooth as necessary and nonnegative.

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt much can be done when you have the "current" value of $f$ dependent on "future" values.

Comment: What support can we expect these functions to have?

Comment: The integral is a correllation over a symmetric interval around $t$. Maybe you can rewrite it as a convolution and $f(t)$ as a dirac impulse convolution.

Answer (score 1):

See the first result of this [work](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02022967). I think that this inequality is called of Gronwall-Bellman (or Gronwall-Bellman-Bihari) inequality.